# VB.net - Open local sqlite table

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm trying to open a locally stored file (SQLite) just to pull some lines from specific tables. The issue that I'm having is that I keep getting errors that the connection could not be made (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) which makes perfect sense because this is not a sql server it is just information stored in a local database file. So am I going about this the wrong way or is this the only method to process a .db or similar file and I've overlooked something?

```
    Dim connection As String = "Data Source=" & Form1.connstring & "; Integrated Security=true"
    Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection
    Dim SQLcmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader

    SQLConn.ConnectionString = connection
    SQLConn.Open()

    SQLcmd.Connection = SQLConn
    SQLcmd.CommandText = SQLstr
    SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
    While SQLdr.Read()
        MessageBox.Show(SQLdr.ToString)
        Form1.ListBox1.Text = SQLdr.ToString
    End While

    SQLdr.Close()
    SQLConn.Close()
```

Form1.connstring is the full file path. 
I've tried a few different types of syntax on the "Data Source=" line to try and reference this as a local file but so far I'm lost.

This is for a tool that will have to scan different database files - all locally stored - to farm information

***EDIT***

Solution:

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite 'Interop available on NuGet

Public Class _SQLite

Public Shared Sub SQLInq()
    'Value to search as SQL Query - return first match
    Dim SQLstr As String = "Select * FROM FsFileVersion WHERE FileDescription_LTH = 'Entry' LIMIT 1;"

    'Define file to open - .path passed from parent form
    Dim connection As String = "Data Source=" & _Compression.path
    Dim SQLConn As New SQLiteConnection(connection)
    Dim SQLcmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQLConn)
    Dim SQLdr As SQLiteDataReader
    SQLConn.Open()

    SQLcmd.Connection = SQLConn
    SQLcmd.CommandText = SQLstr
    SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()

    'For each query returned
    While SQLdr.Read()
        'Insert into textbox
        Form1.Textbox1.Text = (SQLdr.GetString(SQLdr.GetOrdinal("FileVersion_LTH")))
    End While

    'End the connection
    SQLdr.Close()
    SQLConn.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the classes provided by the specific ADO.NET provider for SQLite.
First, however you need to install the bits required downloading them from the [source site](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).
Be sure to read carefully about the versions for 64bit and 32bit provider and supported framework.

After that, you need to reference the provider in your project references section and add the appropriate `Imports System.Data.SQLite` statement in your source file (replacing the `System.Data.SqlClient` ones)

Finally you need to change your code to use the SQLite classes and [fix your connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/) for SQLite syntax

```
Dim connection As String = "Data Source=" & Form1.connstring & ";Version=3"
Dim SQLConn As New SQLiteConnection
Dim SQLcmd As New SQLiteCommand
Dim SQLdr As SQLiteDataReader

SQLConn.ConnectionString = connection
SQLConn.Open()

SQLcmd.Connection = SQLConn
SQLcmd.CommandText = SQLstr
SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
While SQLdr.Read()
    MessageBox.Show(SQLdr(fieldIndexHere).ToString)
    Form1.ListBox1.Text = SQLdr(fieldIndexHere).ToString
End While

SQLdr.Close()
SQLConn.Close()
```

Comment: Awesome. Quick answer and spot-on. Used NuGET to grab the sqlite binaries

Comment: Updated answer to fix a little error in using the SQLiteDataReader (need the field index or name to read)